# How to use MarketPlaceReviewTask in a WindowsPhone 8.1 project?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

In my Windows Phone 8.1 project I would like to add a "Rate this app" and "View my other apps" options but I couldn't. I already know how to code a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight project, however I couldn't it over here. Do you know how to use in WP 8.1?

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

MarketplaceReviewTask marketplaceReviewTask = new MarketplaceReviewTask();
marketplaceReviewTask.Show();
```

Comment: Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store:reviewapp?appid=" + APP_ID));

Answer (score 0):

It's a one-liner now:

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store:reviewapp?appid=" + CurrentApp.AppId));
```